# How can I get Beautifulsoup to print text from paragraphs that are nested inside of a div?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to web scraping and using beautiful soup 4. I was trying to get just the text printed from inside the <p></p> tags which are nested under a div. I am able to get them to print but the tags still appear and the beautiful soup won't let me use the .text function to extract the text from the paragraph tags. Is there a better way to do this or am I just doing it wrong?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

url = "https://www.wuxiaworld.com/novel/tales-of-demons-and-gods/tdg-chapter-1"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
src = req.content
print(req.status_code)
print()
bs4soup = soup(src, 'lxml')
bs4soup.prettify()

# div = bs4soup.find('div', attrs={'id': 'chapter-content'})
# par = div.find_all('p')
# print(par)  #  This just prints all of the <p> tags on the same line.

for paragraph in bs4soup.find('div', attrs={'id': 'chapter-content'}):
    print(paragraph)
```

This is what my output looks like

```
<p><strong>Chapter 1 - Reborn</strong></p>
<p><span style="">On the colossal St. Ancestral Mountain range, sunlight shined through the gap between the mountains into the deep canyons. On the hillside beside the valley, some snow remained.</span></p>
<p><span style="">Even though it’s already the early summer, the snow has yet to melt. The cold here is exceptionally long. The roars of beasts can occasionally be heard.</span></p>
```

and continues down like that for all the lines in the paragraph.

I tried to use the text function built into Beautiful Soup but when I added that to the paragraph.text it spit out an `AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'text'`

What would be the best way to tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the structure of page looks something like this:

```
<div id="chapter-content">
    <script></script>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    ...
</div>
```

You can use `.find_all()` method to get all `p` tags and just print text from those tags:

```
for paragraph in bs4soup.find('div', attrs={'id': 'chapter-content'}).find_all('p'):
    print(paragraph.text)
```

Output will look like this:

```
Chapter 1 - Reborn
On the colossal St. Ancestral Mountain range, sunlight shined through the gap between the mountains into the deep canyons. On the hillside beside the valley, some snow remained.
Even though it’s already the early summer, the snow has yet to melt. The cold here is exceptionally long. The roars of beasts can occasionally be heard.
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because you are predicting that all the children of the div selected are **p**, sadly not!

You can try by writing this code:

```
main_div = bs4soup.find('div', attrs={'id': 'chapter-content'}) # recover it first.
for item in main_div:
    print(item.name)
```

Then, you will see tags different than **p** and you're getting the error because some of them don't contain the **.text** attribute.

To solve it, you can check each tag if it's a **p** inside the loop:

```
main_div = bs4soup.find('div', attrs={'id': 'chapter-content'})
for item in main_div:
    if item.name == "p": # Here the work
       print(item.text)
```

Or, continue to find all the **p** tags inside that div, which I recommend.

```
main_div = bs4soup.find('div', attrs={'id': 'chapter-content'})
p_tags = main_div.find_all("p") # You got only p tags
# Each p tag have .text attribute, looping now is secure
for p in p_tage:
    print(p.text)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, including an explanation of how or why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: I've done it, and I improved the quality of my post, thank you btw for taking care of the quality of MY POST.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. The error explanation really helps. I kept wondering why the .text wasn't working! This clears it up perfectly.